# Frame not displaying | python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display my frame in my window but for some reason its giving me a blank window. It's my first time using classes with tkinter do i need to call it in the object?

```html
from customtkinter import *

class app(CTk):
    def __init__(self, title, size):
        
        # main setup
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f'{size[0]}x{size[1]}')
        self.minsize(size[0],size[1])
        # widget
        self.menu = CTkFrame(self)       
        # run
        self.mainloop()


    class Menu(CTkFrame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth = 0.3, relheight = 1)
            
            self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
            heading_var = StringVar(value="Ethan") 
            def heading_combo(choice):
                print(choice)
            heading = CTkComboBox(self, value=["Ethan","Brock", "Liam"], command=heading_combo,variable=heading_var)
            
            self.columnconfigure((0,1,2),weight=1, uniform='a')
            self.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4),weight=1, uniform='a')

            heading.pack()







app('Scoring Software', (600,600))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a blank window because you didn't call a `pack()`, `grid()` or `place()` method on the self.menu widget.

To fix this you can add `self.menu.pack()` on line 13. The full code is the following:

```py
from customtkinter import *


class app(CTk):
    def __init__(self, title, size):
        # main setup
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f'{size[0]}x{size[1]}')
        self.minsize(size[0], size[1])
        # widget
        self.menu = CTkFrame(self)
        self.menu.pack()
        # run
        self.mainloop()

    class Menu(CTkFrame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=0.3, relheight=1)

            self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
            heading_var = StringVar(value="Ethan")

            def heading_combo(choice):
                print(choice)

            heading = CTkComboBox(self, values=["Ethan", "Brock", "Liam"], command=heading_combo, variable=heading_var)

            self.columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1, uniform='a')
            self.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1, uniform='a')

            heading.pack()


app('Scoring Software', (600, 600))
```

But your code seems weird, you are creating a Menu class but not using it.

If you thought doing this `class Menu(CTkFrame):` would completly overwrite the CTkFrame class, you are wrong, it just creates a new class with modified methods.

To use the Menu class you created, you should replace the 12th line by this:

```py
self.menu = self.Menu(self)
```

Hope I helped you, have a nice day